# Mongodb deleteMany or dump with specified date

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Maybe this subject often question to ask, but I not find what I want it.
I have a collection with keys and values like this:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("6142f3a47245125aef7ffcc0"),
  addTime: '2021-09-16 14:35:00',
  editTime: '2021-09-16 14:35:00'
}
```

I want to dump before August 2021. What syntax do I have to use?
I trying in roboT and mongo shell, before dump I try find first.

```
db.collections.find({addTime:{$lte:new Date("2021-09-01")}})
```

and the result is

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 3714ms
```

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure addTime is actually saved as Date and not a string that looks like a Date?

Comment: hello Rani,  addTime is string.. I gonna check another field whos looks like Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `$expr` operator to temporarily convert the string to a date-time value and then perform your query.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$lte": [
      {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$addTime",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  // <- Your date time format in string
          "onNull": new Date("9999-09-01"),  // <- Default calue if query key doesnt exist (Dont modify this value, unless required)
        }
      },
      new Date("2021-09-01"),  // <- Your datetime query value (can also be `ISODate` format)
    ],
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i8RyFO0QhJ8)

Comment: hello @hhharsha36, 
I trying the method you gave, but why is this still Fetched 0 record(s) in 12224ms
...

Comment: Hi @empoy, Are you sure that the string stored in the `addTime` key is of format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`?
If you are running it on Mongo Shell, try to replace `new Date` with `ISODate`.
Finally, make sure that at least one record exists within the date being compared with.
Let me know if you are still facing difficulties, I am happy to help :)
P.S., which programming language are you using?

Comment: sorry to slow response, pretty sure addTime key is format %Y-%m-%d, test the syntax until now, I running from Mongo Shell and try > new date with > ISODate, but isn't work.. andd
and whoaaa, finally I got it! I trying your syntax convert first.
Thank you so much @hhharsha36, youre the hero for saving the day!!
:')

I using Java.
if we have 1 key value, like archiveMonth  202109 is use expression conversion too?

Comment: Hi @empoy, I am glad that you are able to solve it. Yes, you can use 1 key-value like archiveMonth 202109 for conversions too, read through the `$dateFromString` MongoDB documentation and figure out your date format. Don't forget to mark the answer correct so that it would help others struggling with similar problems :)

Comment: hi @hhharsha36 , very well noted.
but my reputation still 13, haha. wait and I can mark the answer correct.
Once more, thank you so much @hhharsha36! :)